# Why my Soffid JSON REST Web Services Connector does not update an object in the target system?

Tags: json, rest, web, connector

I am trying to connect my Soffid 3 server with our custom web application named Schrift. I am using а JSON REST Web Services Connector for this purpose. I added REST Web service plugin and then configured an agent with JSON/XML/SOAP Rest webservice type.
Loading of objects is working fine. My REST connector connects to the web service successfully and gets data of the accounts.
The problem is when I am trying to update some data (for example, I am trying to lock an account), nothing happens. And unfortunately I don't know what **should** be happening. When should REST connector send updated data to the managed system and in which way? I didn't find any log entries saying that REST connector was trying to update an object on managed system. Maybe I did smth wrong or missed something.
I would appreciate for any help. I can post any conf or log details if you need.

---

**Update#1**
(I did some investigation after the first answer)

1. I checked the agent settings: *Read only* and *Manual account creation* are set to **no**
2. The account was set to unmanaged type, but I succeeded in changing its type to *shared* and then to *single* without getting an error. Now it is set to **single**
3. The task queue is empty.

Also I've checked that update method is present and update properties are set correctly. *updateParams* is not set (it means that all attributes should be sent to the managed system).
But when I change status of the account (from Enable to Disable), nothing happens.
In the console log I can see only these lines
`14-Sep-2021 13:26:29.708 INFO [BPM-Scheduler:192.168.7.121:1] com.soffid.iam.bpm.job.JobExecutorThread.run No job to execute`
When I manually run the task Analize impact for changes on Schrift, Execution log shows

```
Changes detected for accounts
=============================
NO CHANGE DETECTED
Changes detected for roles
=============================
NO CHANGE DETECTED
```

---

**Update#2**
After many attempts I made some progress. Now when I make some changes in the account, the task named *UpdateAccount baklykov@irf.com.ua@Schrift* appears, but runs with an error.
At first it was `415 Unsupported Media Type` error as I wrote in comments, but now it looks a little different

```
Throws exception updating object : Extensible object [type = account]
  EmployeeEmail: baklykov@irf.com.ua
  IsLockedOut: true (log truncated) ...
caused by Unexpected response, Content-Type: null
```

---

**Update#3**
I found out that soffid's request for updating the object was in improper format (all the parameters were passed in the html request instead of putting them in json body)
After researching I found a method's property called *Encoding* and set it to **application/json** value.
Now the parameters are passed in json body (that's what I need), but now the problem is that soffid puts **all the parameters** in json body, including the key parameter by which the object for updating should be determined. My guess this is the reason why the object in the target system is still not updated.
In other words my application expects a request like this:

```
https://myapp.mysite.com/api/v1/Soffid/Employees?EmployeeEmail=baklykov%40irf.com.ua : 
{"EmployeeLastName":"Baklykov","EmployeeFirstName":"Ivan"}
```

but Soffid sends this:

```
https://myapp.mysite.com/api/v1/Soffid/Employees: 
{"EmployeeLastName":"Baklykov","EmployeeFirstName":"Ivan","EmployeeEmail":"baklykov@irf.com.ua"}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The system should have created a UpdateAccount task in the task queue. Please, verify:

1. The task engine is in automatic mode. In read-only or manual mode, no task will be created.
2. If you are updating an account, check the account is not set as unmanaged. In that case, no tasks is created.
3. Finally, verify the task queue has not held the task up.

Comment: 1. Agent settings _Read only_ and _Manual account creation_ set to **no**. 
2. Account set as unmanaged - I think this is the case. But when I try to change its type, I get an error (code 500):
InternalErrorException: To change a shared account to single user account, a sigle owner ad no users must be specified

Comment: I managed to change type of the account to **shared** - is it ok? (previously I tried to set its type to _single_ and got an error). But when I try to disable the account, no task appears (I am using Sync server monitoring page to view tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the engine mode? Look at Main Menu > Administration > Configure Soffid > Integration engine > Smart engine settings

It should be set to automatic.

Comment: Oops, Task engine mode was set to _manual_, I switched it to **automatic**

Comment: After several tries I made some progress: now I have a task at _Sync server monitoring - View tasks_ page that finished with an error. The log says:   ```Throws exception updating object : Extensible object [type = account]
  EmployeeEmail: baklykov@irf.com.ua
  IsLockedOut: true (log truncated) ...
caused by Error on invocation: 415 Unsupported Media Type
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-2d41883b0c9d994ab5dce7c0bf7f89ee-d7330a0abd13d34b-01"}```   What could it mean?

Comment: Probably you missed setting the content type for the REST method.
The error 415 is thrown by the target application server.

Comment: Yes, the request has reached the target system, but it formed incorrectly. How can I set it right? I can't find something similar to the content type setting.